# AssertionError: Unsafe to transition to read-only state

Tags: fluid-framework

So I had a working project with fluid that ran in the browser. Then, I decided to add the `tslog` npm package to my `project.json` and then import it into one of my typescript files using `import { Logger} from 'tslog'`. Now when I try to run my project again in the browser, the page doesnt load and I see this assertion:

```
"AssertionError: Unsafe to transition to read-only state!
    at DeltaManagerProxy.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:160069:58)
    at DeltaManagerProxy.emit (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:57977:5)
    at DeltaManager.listener (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:286:56)
    at DeltaManager.emit (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:57982:7)
    at DeltaManager.set_readonlyPermissions (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:154358:18)
    at DeltaManager.close (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:154720:14)
    at Container.close (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:152814:28)
    at http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@fluidframework/webpack-component-loader/dist/fluid-loader.bundle.js:153010:18"
```

I'm not sure what this means as the two actions (me adding `tslog`) and me getting this error seem unrelated.  I'm not even sure what kind of additional information I should provide to help diagnose this issue.

What does this error mean and how can adding a npm module cause it?

Answer (score 1):

That's a surprising error. One possibility is that it's just a broken connection caused by installing while the system was running. Restarting the service, reinstalling (delete node_modules, `npm i`), and starting (`npm start`) may fix the issue.

That error indicates that there was a transition to a "read-only" connection. (This is the connection between the container and the delta service.) While this transition should only happen from "disconnected," this assert flags scenarios where the connection goes from readonly to readonly or connected to readonly.

If you're familiar with the debug tools, you may be able to see which issue is causing your error. If you can link a larger code sample that'd be helpful for debugging.